# Using an "or" operator between variables for a loop in Stata

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I have a set of variables that are string variables. For each value in the string, I create a series of binary (0, 1) variables.

Let's say my variables are `Engine1 Engine2 Engine3`.
The possible values are `BHM`, `BMN`, `HLC`, or missing (coded as `"."`).
The values of the variables are mutually exclusive, except missing.

In a hypothetical example, to write the new variables, I would write the following code:

```
egen BHM=1 if Engine1=="BHM"|Engine2=="BHM"|Engine3=="BHM"`
replace BHM=0 if BHM==.
gen BMN=1 if Engine1=="BMN"|Engine2=="BMN"|Engine3=="BMN"`
replace BMN=0 if BMN==.
gen HLC=1 if Engine1=="HLC"|Engine2=="HLC"|Engine3=="HLC"
replace HLC=0 if HLC==.
```

How could I rewrite this code in a loop? I don't understand how to use the "or" operator `|` in a loop.

Comment: Please note http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for future questions. Code we could run with self-contained data examples or accessible Stata-readable datasets is usually better than hypothetical code. (Your hypothetical code wasn't even tested, as the first line is illegal.)

Answer (score 2):

First note that `egen` is a typo for `gen` in your first line.

Second, note that

```
gen BHM=1 if Engine1=="BHM"|Engine2=="BHM"|Engine3=="BHM"
replace BHM=0 if BHM==.
```

can be rewritten in one line:

```
gen BHM = Engine1=="BHM"|Engine2=="BHM"|Engine3=="BHM"
```

Now learn about the handy `inlist()` function:

```
gen BHM = inlist("BHM", Engine1, Engine2, Engine3)
```

If that looks odd, it's because your mathematics education led you to write things like

if x = 1 or y = 1 or z = 1

but only convention stops you writing

if 1 = x or 1 = y or 1 = z

The final trick is to write a loop:

```
foreach v in BHM BMN HLC { 
    gen `v' = inlist("`v'", Engine1, Engine2, Engine3) 
}
```

It's not clear what you are finding difficult about `|`. Your code was fine in that respect.

An bug often seen in learner code is like

```
gen y = 1 if x == 11|12|13
```

which is legal Stata but almost never what you want. Stata parses it as

```
gen y = 1 if (x == 11)|12|13
```

and uses its rule that non-zero arguments mean true in true-or-false evaluations. Thus `y` is 1 if

```
x == 11
```

or

```
12 // a non-zero argument, evaluates as true regardless of x
```

or

```
13 // same comment
```

The learner needs

```
gen y = 1 if (x == 11)|(x == 12)|(x == 13)
```

where the parentheses can be omitted. That's repetitive, so

```
gen y = 1 if inlist(x, 11, 12, 13)
```

can be used instead.

For more on `inlist()` see 
[articles here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0026)
and 
[here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046) Section 2.2 
and 
[here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0058).

For more on true and false in Stata, see [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/index.html)